# Setting a custom itemRenderer in a Flex3 ComboBox on specific list items after combobox creation

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I'm trying to set a specific list item in a mx combobox to have a custom item renderer, the problem is that I cannot do this via mxml, it needs to be done via actionscript at a later stage, eg: combobox gets created, combobox  gets populated, user does other tasks, combobox needs to set one or more items in the combobox to have icons (via item renderer)..

I can do this via the onChange event, but it only applies the icon when the combobox is opened and there is a slight delay so you can see the icon being added.

Thanks in advance for any help
J

Comment: It sounds like you have it working, but not quick enough for your preference.  Show your code, preferably a running sample.  Also specify which SDK you are using.  ComboBox had a significant change in how it handles the drop down between Flex 3.4 and 3.5 .

Answer (score 0):

The normal answer for this is to not do this in the onChange, but to change something in the ComboBox's dataProvider and let the itemRenderer handle it instead.

i.e. in the itemRenderer

```
<mx:Image id="icon" source={data.icon} visible={data.icon} includeInLayout={data.icon} />
```

Setting the icon property in whichever item you want to show the icon for. If icon is null, nothing gets shown.